# Insert rows of Word table to Assess Database Table rows

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access table with the fields

```
ID
Field1
Field2
Field3
```

I also have a word table with headers

```
ID | Field1 | Field2 | Field3
```

How can I import automatically all the data from the table into an assess database from the word file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing automatically doesnt sound easy, but you could do it programmatically.

From Access, you'd do something like this:

```
dim base as string: base = "INSERT INTO tblname (ID, Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES ("
dim sql as string
dim ii as long
dim jj as long
dim wrd as object
dim wrdDoc as object
'
docmd.setwarnings false
set wrd = createObject("Word.Application")
wrd.visible = false
set wrdDoc = wrd.Documents.Add("name of word document containing table")
with wrdDoc.Tables(1)   'assuming first table in document
    for ii = ? to .Rows.Count      'if the table has column headings, ? = 2, else 1
        sql = base
        for jj = 1 to 4            '4 = count of columns
            sql = sql & iif(jj = 1, "", ",") & CStr(.Cell(ii, jj))
        next jj
        sql = sql & ")"
        docmd.runsql sql
    next ii
end with
docmd.setwarnings true
wrd.Quit
set wrddoc = nothing
set wrd = nothing
```